# play framework 2: h2 in memory database mysql compatibility mode: escaping characters

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-2.0, h2

I'm working in development mode with an H2 in memory database, but I'd like it to behave as much as possible like a mysql database (see http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility)

this is my configuration in application.conf file:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"
```

to test it I just run "play" and from play's console I issue "h2-browser" and in the url jdbc field I enter "jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1"

the following statements work ok in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `tmp` (
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
insert into tmp (name) values ('slash: \\, simple quotes \', double quotes \" -');
select * from tmp;
```

but in the h2 console I get an error, and the only character I can escape is the single quotes, just by preceding it with another single quote. (Also tried entering 'SET MODE MySQL;')

Is there some way to have h2 behave like mysql from play's framework h2-browser? or is it just a limitation of h2?

Comment: seems like just using double single quotes works on both, mysql and h2...

Comment: The ANSI SQL standard defines that you need to use two single quotes within a string, so `' ... \' ... '` is not correct, you need to use `' ... '' ... '`. This is documented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The link you provided, http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility, documents the exact compatibility features H2 supports. Things that are not documented are not supported. In this case it seems the problem is the 'backslash' escaping within a String literal:

```
'slash: \\, simple quotes \', double quotes \" -'
```

The backslash is not an escape character for ANSI SQL; to escape a single quote you need to use two single quotes. The problem is this might not work for MySQL as the single backslash is still an escape character:

```
'slash: \, simple quotes '', double quotes " -'
```

For this problem, a solution is to use the [ANSI mode for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-mode.html), another solution is to always use bind variables for String literals (PreparedStatement within JDBC).